# Standalone, self-contained s(n)printf implementations

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, c, embedded-systems

I need to do some string formatting for debugging purposes on a platform with no OS libraries, no C/C++ standard libraries (well, sort of, it's complicated) and no runtime for another language.

Now, I know that that there are quite a few out-of-libc implementations of printf/sprintf/snprintf, but some are very partial; some have quirks or bugs; some actually do depend on standard library code (say, `itoa`); etc.

I would like to be able to compare the strengths and weaknesses of these in order to choose one.

Requirements:

- Libre license
- Gratis
- Covers most `printf()` formatting `%`-codes

Non-requirements:

- Doesn't have to be strictly C, can be C++
- Doesn't have to be independent of all C library *headers* (as opposed to code), but must be frugal about this so I might be able to lift stuff from the header files as necessary

Preferences:

- Covers all of the standard `printf()` formatting `%`-codes
- License more permissive than GPL
- Non-convoluted code
- `snprintf()` rather than `sprintf()`
- `vsnprintf()` in addition to `snprintf()`

Comment: You will be coding and debugging for years to implement a 'clean' set of the *print*() functions.  (and it will be huge)  You did not mention WHY you could not use a stand alone `libc`.  I would strongly suggest downloading such a 'standalone' library and linking that into your application

Comment: @user3629249: I don't intend to code this myself, I'm looking for a recommendation for something pre-existing. To answer your question - no such libc is available, nor can it be; much of the functionality is not physically supported - I'm writing code for a GPU. I didn't mention that in the actual question since I thought I'd make it a bit more general.